# Stormcrawler - how does the es.status.filterQuery work?

Tags: elasticsearch, web-crawler, stormcrawler

I am using stormcrawler to put data into some Elasticsearch indexes, and I have a bunch of URL's in the status index, with a variety of statuses - DISCOVERED, FETCHED, ERROR, etc.

I was wondering if I could tell StormCrawler to just crawl the urls that are https and with the status: DISCOVERED and if that would actually work. I have the es-conf.yaml set as follows:

```
es.status.filterQuery: "-(url:https* AND status:DISCOVERED)"
```

Is that correct? how does SC make use of the es.status.filterQuery? Does it run a search and apply the value as a filter to retrieve only the applicable documents to fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [code of the AggregationSpout](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/src/main/java/com/digitalpebble/stormcrawler/elasticsearch/persistence/AggregationSpout.java#L117).

> how does SC make use of the es.status.filterQuery? Does it run a
>   search and apply the value as a filter to retrieve only the applicable
>   documents to fetch?

yes, it filters the queries sent to the ES shards. This is useful for instance to process a subset of a crawl.

It is a positive filter i.e. the documents must match the query in order to be retrieved; you'd need to remove the - for it to do what you described.